# lib_alsa Cannot access file

Tags: c++, fedora

Firstly thanks for your help.

I have to do a c++ project using lib_alsa and portaudio, but when I execute him (with CMake) I have this **problem**

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3956:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /root/.conan/data/libalsa/1.1.9/_/_/package/51e96d1346424f5ef647616231906873cd225eb3/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
ALSA lib conf.c:3956:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /root/.conan/data/libalsa/1.1.9/_/_/package/51e96d1346424f5ef647616231906873cd225eb3/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:1
babel_client: sources/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:1453: BuildDeviceList: Assertion `devIdx < numDeviceNames' failed.
[1]    17399 abort (core dumped)  ./babel_client 200 200
```

I don't understand and don't find any answers on the internet. (I m on fedora 32 (i don't know if its important xD)) and sorry for my English I'm just a Frenchman :D

Comment: You probably should not be developing or running software as root. Does that session have access to the same environment variables as your regular user account?

Comment: I'm not sure... but i tried with sudo and there are no diff

Comment: You need to run it *under your regular user desktop session*, not as root (not directly, not using sudo). The "/root/.conan" in your error message tells me you at least invoked conan as root and probably are running your code as root.

Comment: i think i am on my  regular user session ```╭─pgmendormi@desktop-u3ems4s ~/blablabla/blabla/bla/build/bin  ‹audioClass*› ```

Is it possible pgmendormi is not my regular user session and i'm always there as a root?

Comment: No, a root session would probably be something like `root@...`. Then I wonder where the conan warnings come from. Did you run conan as root or something?

Answer (score 1):

You ran `cmake` as root. I am sure you have something like `conan_cmake_run(...)` to run conan during cmake (which is great).

But note, conan stores all its database and file in `~/.conan`. If `${USER}` is root, then this goes into a read-write protected `/root/.conan`, which is obvious from the output you send.

This won't work. Run `cmake` (or particularly `conan`) NOT AS ROOT.

Do the following, `rm CMakeCache.txt`, run `cmake` again, and NOT AS ROOT. Run `make` and your application.

I may fail differently -- but better.